# How does django treat login/signup based on modal?

Tags: jquery, django, bootstrap-modal

I'm using modal for `login/signup` in `django`.
(http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/modal-login-with-jquery-effects)

But I wonder how `django` treat this in template rendering.

As you can see above url, it has only one `html` file, say, `login.html`.

In django `views`, I have two views named `LoginView` and `SignupView`.

These are what I thought as problems.

1. Each `View` gonna render `template` :

   - `LoginView` --> `login.html`
   - `SignupView` --> `signup.html`

but as you can see above, if I used modal, there is only one `html` file for both `signup` and `login`. I want to know how I can deal with it.

2. Also, Each `view` gonna pass its `form`, say, `UserCreationForm`, `CustomLoginForm` for getting input from user. But if there were only one `html` file, would there be conflict between those `forms`?

Thanks.

Comment: You can put it all in one view, then do the visual effects in css, or a django library that hides content based on conditions.

Comment: A few years back I had the same problem. I have successfully managed to implement it. here's the link for future reference : [link](http://www.nikhilshirsath.com/blog/post_detail/signup-and-login-in-djangio-through-bootstrap-modal/)

Answer (score 1):

1) You can move both of them into one view that returns both of the forms, with different names.

```
signup_form = UserCreationForm()  
login_form = CustomLoginForm()   
context = {"signup_form": signup_form, "login_form": login_form, **other_kwargs}   
return render(request, context, content_type=...)
```

2) There's no problem with a page that contains several forms. Since the forms are being rendered in different names, one idea is to distinguish which form gets posted, using a hidden input, so basically in your html, you do something like:

```
<form method="POST" action="URL">
       input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="login_form"  
       {{ login_form.as_table }}    
       input type="submit"    
</form>

<form method="POST" action="URL">
       input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="signup_form"   
       {{ signup_form.as_table }}               
       input type="submit"    
</form>
```

You can also point URL to a single view, handle which form was submitted using the form_name key inside the POST parameters. Or you can have them point to other URLs, send ajax requests or any other way you prefer.