# Django Modal For User Login/Register - Form Render Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm trying to create a login/register modal based on the JS/Bootstrap here:

https://www.creative-tim.com/product/login-and-register-modal

I'm just looking for guidance as I'm having an issue displaying the form inputs on my modal.  The modals will pop up fine upon click, yet the form inputs are not appearing.

If i visit the page accounts/sign_in or accounts/sign_up and click on one of the buttons, then i do get the popup with the form inputs (for the most part).

Thus, i think i must be improperly handling the render in my login_form view.

I created this 'login_form' view following some guidance [from this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091589/how-does-django-treat-login-signup-based-on-modal)

```
//views.py

def login_form(request):
   signup_form = UserCreationForm()  
   login_form = AuthenticationForm()   
   context = {"signup_form": signup_form, "login_form": login_form}   
   return render(request, 'layout2.html', context)
```

and my url's:

```
//urls.py

app_name = "accounts"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'sign_in/$', views.login_form, name='sign_in'),
    url(r'sign_up/$', views.login_form, name='sign_up'),
```

this is the relevant modal code in my layout2.html file:

```
 <div class="form loginBox">
                                <form method="POST" action="{% url 'accounts:sign_in' %}">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="login_form">
                                    {{ login_form.as_p }}    
                                    <input type="submit" onclick="loginAjax()">
                                 </form>

                          </div>
                       </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="box">
                      <div class="content registerBox" style="display:none;">
                       <div class="form">
                            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'accounts:sign_up' %}" html="{:multipart=>true}" data-remote="true" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="signup_form">
                                    {{ signup_form.as_p }}    
                                    <input type="submit" onclick="loginAjax()">
                                 </form>
                          </div>
```

Not sure if this is relevant to my issue in any way, but just in case here is JS handling modal pop ups:

```
/*
 *
 * login-register modal
 * Autor: Creative Tim
 * Web-autor: creative.tim
 * Web script: http://creative-tim.com
 * 
 */
function showRegisterForm(){
    $('.loginBox').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('.registerBox').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.login-footer').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $('.register-footer').fadeIn('fast');
        });
        $('.modal-title').html('Register with');
    }); 
    $('.error').removeClass('alert alert-danger').html('');

}
function showLoginForm(){
    $('#loginModal .registerBox').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('.loginBox').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.register-footer').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $('.login-footer').fadeIn('fast');    
        });

        $('.modal-title').html('Login with');
    });       
     $('.error').removeClass('alert alert-danger').html(''); 
}

function openLoginModal(){
    showLoginForm();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');    
    }, 230);

}
function openRegisterModal(){
    showRegisterForm();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');    
    }, 230);

}

function loginAjax(){
    /*   Remove this comments when moving to server
    $.post( "/login", function( data ) {
            if(data == 1){
                window.location.replace("/home");            
            } else {
                 shakeModal(); 
            }
        });
    */

/*   Simulate error message from the server   */
     shakeModal();
}

function shakeModal(){
    $('#loginModal .modal-dialog').addClass('shake');
             $('.error').addClass('alert alert-danger').html("Invalid email/password combination");
             $('input[type="password"]').val('');
             setTimeout( function(){ 
                $('#loginModal .modal-dialog').removeClass('shake'); 
    }, 1000 ); 
}
```

--------------UPDATE ON VIEW---------------

Here is what it looks like on homepage if i click on Login:

[image]

And this is what it looks like if i go to accounts/sign_in and click on sign_in button:

[image]

UPDATE Here is my updatd Home view with added

```
class Home(generic.TemplateView):
    model = Deal
    template_name = 'test.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Home, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        today = datetime.datetime.today()
        deals = Deal.objects.all()
        context['deals'] = deals.filter(Q(date_expires__gte=today))
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        context['categories'] = categories
        signup_form = UserCreationForm()  
        login_form = AuthenticationForm()   
        context["signup_form"] = signup_form
        context["login_form"] = login_form
        return context
```

Comment: can you show what you get?, also did you try with different browsers?

Comment: just posted the actual view of what i see....and just tried in different browser (edge) and seems the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are attaching your `def login_form(request):` function to the `sig_in`, `sign_up` view and not in the home page just add and it should work as you expect

```
url(r'^$', views.login_form, name='')
```

As you already had the view `home` just add into the context:

```
signup_form = UserCreationForm()  
login_form = AuthenticationForm()  
context["signup_form"] = signup_form
context["login_form"] = login_form
```

Comment: hmm..okay, but i already have a different view for the home page which renders all of the home page content.  how exactly would i make this work?

Comment: in that case just pass through the render your form. Is `layout2.html` the same template for `home` page?, remember add the {{ login_form.as_p }}  in your template

Comment: ok, still slightly confused (sorry) but yes my home.html is just extending the layout2.html template, so that would include the modal code. I have a Home view that is rendering the home.html template---how exactly would i include the login_form as well?

Comment: Not problem, if you're extending `layout2.html` just pass your form and that's it like `context = {"signup_form": signup_form, "login_form": login_form}   
   return render(request, 'home.html', context)`

Comment: ok..so if i think i understand correctly, i just moved all of that former login_form view code into my 'home' view.  I pasted this update at the end of the code in original post..I also changed the action in my modal forms to `{% url 'home' %}`  still unfortunately having same issue

Comment: add the home view to the question

Comment: delete this `context = {"signup_form": signup_form, "login_form": login_form}` and into the function add `context["signup_form"]= .... context["login_form"] = ..`

Comment: BOOM --that's it!  Thanks buddy!  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: did you add `self.signup_form` or just `signup_form` how that even work

Comment: no just `signup_form` (i updated Home view above)....i haven't quite tested that the form is working properly yet (just know that it is appearing).  I guess maybe i need self in there?

Comment: nop, just if it's outside a function. When you use `self` you are calling an attribute of a class