# Django Modal for User Login with AJAX doesn't POST sucessfully

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

**Django 3 / AJAX / Jquery**
I'm trying to set up a login modal when the user clicks on a save button and isn't logged in yet.

I'm following pretty much from here [Django Modal For User Login/Register - Form Render Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49041794/django-modal-for-user-login-register-form-render-issue)

To set up a login modal on the homepage. My modal loads when it's supposed, and the login form renders. But I'm stuck after getting the POST 200 from the server but not login in. Nothing happens.

I don't understand if I need a different URL for the POST. As far as I understand, I'm posting my form on the same home template, from Django default auth, so everything occurs on the 'home' view. But I might be mistaken here.

I can login from the default /login/ page, which renders the default /registration/login.html template just fine. So there isn't a problem on the login per se. It must be something on the form posting.

views.py:

```
def home(request):
   wishlisted_list =[]
   produtos = Produto.objects.all()
   paginator = Paginator (produtos, 6)
   page = request.GET.get('page')

   signup_form = UserCreationForm()
   login_form = AuthenticationForm()


  if request.user.is_authenticated:
      wishlisted_list = list(Wishlist.objects.filter(user_id=request.user).values_list('produto_id',flat=True).order_by('produto_id'))

try:
    produtos = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer deliver 1st Page
    produtos = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    if request.is_ajax():
        # If the request is AJAX and the page is out of range
        # return an empty page
        return HttpResponse('')
    # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
    produtos = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

if request.is_ajax():
    return render(request,
                  'produtos/list_ajax.html',
                  {'section': 'produtos', 'produtos': produtos, 'wishlisted_list':wishlisted_list})



return render(request, template_name='home.html', context={"produtos": produtos,'wishlisted_list':wishlisted_list,
                        'signup_form':signup_form, 'login_form':login_form})
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name='home'),]
```

The relevant part of modal.html which renders inside the home view:

```
      <div class="form loginBox">

         <form method="POST" action="{% url 'home' %}" accept-charset="UTF-8">
         {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="login_form">
                   {{ login_form.as_p }}
   <input class="btn btn-default btn-login" type="submit" value="Entrar" onclick="loginAjax()">
                 </form>
                     </div>
```

The JS function that loads the form and the one that POST the form:

```
function showLoginForm(){
    $('#loginModal .registerBox').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('.loginBox').fadeIn('fast');
        $('.register-footer').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $('.login-footer').fadeIn('fast');
        });

        $('.modal-title').html('Entrar com');
    });
     $('.error').removeClass('alert alert-danger').html('');
}


function loginAjax(){

    var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
  // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
      return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

  $.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
      }
      });

  $.post( "/", function( data ) {
          if(data == 1){
                window.location.replace("/");
            } else {

            }
        });
}
```

The server codes (I don't know what is pulling this not found accounts/login error):

```
Not Found: /accounts/login/
[04/Mar/2021 22:23:57] "GET /accounts/login/?next=/add-to-wishlist/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3389
[04/Mar/2021 22:23:59] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 8334
[04/Mar/2021 22:23:59] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 17764
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a redundant question but have you got `path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))` in your top level `urls.py` file?

Comment: I have a custom user app. So I have     path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

Comment: Actually, when I successfully post on Django, a login or a save function that I have on the project, I get a 302 code for the POST. And here I'm getting a 200